# Swiftui Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable Error

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm facing an error says "cannot assign to property" as seen in the preview image.

I get this error when I use the variable inside the struct of View and inside the forEach.

Here's Screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Define your `currentMood` as a `@State` variable:

```
@State var currentMood: String
```

You'll likely need to assign it with `self.currentMood = moodData` (adding `self.`)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)))).

Comment: @DixitAkabari This blog doesn't address the question. `moodCheck` is a SwiftUI View. Those cannot be a class. (Also, blindly changing structs to classes is very dicey advice. That can inject surprising bugs in existing code due to the change of semantics.)